# How to fix failed to link /usr/bin/gradle -> /etc/alternatives/gradle: /usr/bin/gradle exists and it is not a symlink

Tags: linux, bash, gradle, fedora

I got the below error

> failed to link /usr/bin/gradle -> /etc/alternatives/gradle: /usr/bin/gradle exists and it is not a symlink

I want to change the gradle version of my linux fedora from gradle 4.4.1 to gradle 2.14.1.

I have downloaded and extracted the archive of the new gradle file and moved it to `/opt` location on my laptop and ran the below command on terminal:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gradle gradle /opt/gradle-2.14.1-all/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle 2000`

I would like advice on how to change the gradle version of my linux fedora from gradle 4.4.1 to gradle 2.14.1. Thanks!

Comment: If some version of gradle is installed and you want to set to the new version, shouldn't simple `sudo update-alternatives gradle` bring up all selections to choose from?? This question is more proper on the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Your comment is not cohersive because you seem to be saying many things.. can you rephrase what you said in multiple sentences. Thanks

Comment: The purpose of `update-alternatives` is to allow you to *specify* or *select* the provider or version of a package to use. You should be able to simply run `update-alternatives` for `gradle` and select the version. `update-alternatives` then takes care of updating the symlinks. Since this question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the two sites I provided links to. I'd probably start with SuperUser which has a higher volume of traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is fixed. the command below
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gradle gradle /opt/gradle-2.14.1-all/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle 
resolved it